# Erro ao executar comando CREATE TRIGGER no sqlite com Android Studio (near "FROM": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR):)

Tags: java, android-studio, sqlite, trigger, sqlite-studio

Tenho o comando abaixo CREATE em uma STRING e quando executo **execSQL(triggerTeamLeagueClassification)** recebo o seguinte erro: "Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "FROM": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR):".
O mesmo comando é executado perfeitamente no SQLStudio 3.4.1.

Estou utilizando o Android Studio 2021.2.1 e o código é em JAVA.

````
triggerTeamLeagueClassification = "CREATE TRIGGER trigger_team_league_classification\n" +
           "         AFTER INSERT\n" +
           "            ON team_league\n" +
           "      FOR EACH ROW\n" +
           "BEGIN\n" +
           "    UPDATE team_league\n" +
           "       SET punctuation = pp.score\n" +
           "      FROM team_league tl\n" +
           "           INNER JOIN\n" +
           "           league l ON tl.id_league = l.id\n" +
           "           INNER JOIN\n" +
           "           punctuation_position pp ON pp.id_punctuation_type = l.id_punctuation_type AND \n" +
           "                                      pp.position = tl.position\n" +
           "     WHERE team_league.id_league = tl.id_league AND \n" +
           "           team_league.id_team = tl.id_team AND \n" +
           "           team_league.position = tl.position AND \n" +
           "           tl.id_league = NEW.id_league AND \n" +
           "           tl.id_team = NEW.id_team AND \n" +
           "           tl.position = NEW.position;\n" +
           "    INSERT INTO classification SELECT id_team,\n" +
           "                                      id_league,\n" +
           "                                      NULL,\n" +
           "                                      punctuation\n" +
           "                                 FROM team_league\n" +
           "                                WHERE id_team = NEW.id_team AND \n" +
           "                                      id_league = NEW.id_league AND \n" +
           "                                      [match] = NEW.[match] ON CONFLICT (\n" +
           "                                   id_team,\n" +
           "                                   id_league\n" +
           "                               )\n" +
           "                               DO UPDATE SET punctuation_final = punctuation_final + (\n" +
           "                                                                                         SELECT pp.score\n" +
           "                                                                                           FROM team_league tl\n" +
           "                                                                                                INNER JOIN\n" +
           "                                                                                                league l ON tl.id_league = l.id\n" +
           "                                                                                                INNER JOIN\n" +
           "                                                                                                punctuation_position pp ON pp.id_punctuation_type = l.id_punctuation_type AND \n" +
           "                                                                                                                           pp.position = tl.position\n" +
           "                                                                                          WHERE tl.id_league = NEW.id_league AND \n" +
           "                                                                                                tl.id_team = NEW.id_team AND \n" +
           "                                                                                                tl.position = NEW.position\n" +
           "                                                                                     );\n" +
           "END;\n";```
````

Comment: Creio ser o FROM dp UPDATE.

Comment: Era isso mesmo!

Answer (score 0):

Após resposta do amigo ***Motta***, refatorei o UPDATE e funcionou. Obrigado!
Estranho que, como eu disse, no SQLiteStudio funcionava o código anterior.

Segue:

```
UPDATE team_league
       SET punctuation = COALESCE((select pp.score from punctuation_position pp 
            inner join punctuation_type pt on
            pt.id = pp.id_punctuation_type 
            inner join league l on
            l.id_punctuation_type = pt.id
            inner join team_league tl on
            tl.id_league = l.id and 
            tl.position = pp.position
            where tl.id_league = NEW.id_league AND 
                       tl.id_team = NEW.id_team AND 
                       tl.position = NEW.position), 0)
   WHERE id_team = NEW.id_team AND
         id_league = NEW.id_league AND
         match = NEW.match ;
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).